# how to keep a vessel with liquid in it a certain temperature?

Tags: chemical-biology

how do i keep a vessel with liquid in it a certain temperature?
in a room and don't have to buy something expensive?

i am taking a biogas vessel and placing them in different temperatures. 
PLs help me CHAR

Answer (score 2):

In the construction of DIY biogas reactors, it is quite common to rely on Intermediate Bulk Containers (IBC). These are

- affordable
- available in different sizes
- sturdy, particularly when used with baseplate and frame
- stackable

The relevant reactions take place in the absence of oxygen and light.

If you run your reactor outside, which is a good idea, given that the degradation of sulfur-comtaining amino acids yields volatile sulfur-containing compounds, it needs to be insulated.

Typically,

- PU foam (from a spray can)
- styrofoam panels or
- bales of straw

are used for this purpose.

The non-profit [Solar C³ities](http://solarcities.eu/) community provides a lot of background information and practical hints, such as a [detailed instruction how to build  an IBC biodigester](http://solarcities.eu/education/388).